# Matching rows in one data frame with columns in a second

Tags: r, memory, addition

Sample data:

```
t1 <- data.frame(
  CName=c("334","5as4","ggg","bbb"), 
  D1=c(1," ",3,1), 
  D2=c(3,4,5,5)
)

t2 <- data.frame(
  PName=c("zz","yy","xx","ww"), 
  `334`=c(5,6,3,5), 
  "ggg"=c(7,5,4,3), 
  `5as4`=c(9,9,1,1),
  check.names=FALSE
)
```

Producing:

```
t1
  CName D1 D2
1   334  1  3
2  5as4     4
3   ggg  3  5
4   bbb  1  5

t2
  PName 334 ggg 5as4
1    zz   5   7    9
2    yy   6   5    9
3    xx   3   4    1
4    ww   5   3    1
```

I want to match the column `t1$CName` column to the column headings of`t2`.

The Desired output is:

```
   PName  334  ggg  5as4
     D1   1    3     
     D2   3    5    4
1    zz   5    7    9
2    yy   6    5    9
3    xx   3    4    1
4    ww   5    3    1
```

Comment: Why do you think memory is a problem? What error do you get? How large are your data frames?

Comment: @Andrie,  My dataset is about 1000 in size, as my computer is slow, I worry that memory is a problem.  If base on your experiences, it is not a problem. Could you mind to teach me how to do it in general?  I guess I could use the method suggested by Gsee earlier (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424232). But I don't know how to modify it so that new lines can be added based on matching results.  Could you mind to give me a hand?

Comment: I have **completely** rewritten your question in a way that seems to make sense, and have posted an answer that R should easily cope with, even on an old machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you really want to merge the transpose of `t1` with `t2`:

**Step 1:** Create a transposed copy of table `t1`:

```
tt1 <- as.data.frame(t(t1[, -1]), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(tt1) <- t1[, 1]
tt1$PName = rownames(tt1)

tt1
   334 5as4 ggg bbb PName
D1   1        3   1    D1
D2   3    4   5   5    D2
```

**Step 2:** Merge

```
merge(tt1, t2, all=TRUE, sort=FALSE)

  334 5as4 ggg PName  bbb
1   1        3    D1    1
2   3    4   5    D2    5
3   5    9   7    zz <NA>
4   6    9   5    yy <NA>
5   3    1   4    xx <NA>
6   5    1   3    ww <NA>
```

**Step 3:** Now all you have to do is remove the columns you don't need.

```
  334 5as4 ggg PName
1   1        3    D1
2   3    4   5    D2
3   5    9   7    zz
4   6    9   5    yy
5   3    1   4    xx
6   5    1   3    ww
```

---

Even for your stated data size of 1000 entries this should not be a problem for R.

Comment: Thank you very much.  The analysis runs very fast.